# unable to add dependency for com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

In my android app, I am trying to add the dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1
```

and import

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
```

The import is not successful. Could you assist me to resolve this erroe ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradle dependency and the import statement both look correct, so I would assume that this is an issue with Android Studio. You can try invalidating your caches by going to File < Invalidate Caches / Restart and then Invalidate and Restart.